# Gauge SU(2) with real triplet

Tags: standard-model, gauge-theory, covariance, beyond-the-standard-model

I have come across a model of gauge $SU(2)$ with a real triplet. 
The covariant derivative for $SU(2)$ complex doublet is written as $$D_\mu=\partial_\mu-igT^aA^a_\mu$$ where $T^a$ are generators of the group in fundamental representation. Which intuitively tell me for a triplet the covariant derivative should be the same except $T^a$ now are the generators in adjoint representation i.e. a 3x3 matrix. But i have come acros this model of gauge $SU(2)$ with a real triplet which writes kinetic part of the lagrangian as $$(\partial_\mu\phi-gA_\mu \times\phi)^2$$ where phi is a real triplet. Please some one explain me this derivation\origin new covariant derivative(any reference will also be helpful).

Comment: Gibbs and Heaviside strike yet again! More seriously, the Lie algebra (that of $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$) that justifies this questionable notation *is* the cross product algebra: in Lie theory, we write the binary product as a commutator bracket: replace it with $\times$ and you have the cross product algebra of three dimensional vectors.

Answer (score 5):

In general, the covariant derivative acting upon a field in a representation $\rho : G \to V_\rho$, is given by

$$ D = \mathrm{d} - \mathrm{i} g \rho(A) \wedge $$

or, in coordinates/generators, indeed

$$ D_\mu = \partial_\mu - \mathrm{i} g A_\mu^a \rho(T^a)$$

where $\rho(T^a)$ are the generators of $G$ in the chosen representation.

Now, for the triplet of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ (the rep labeled by $j = 1$), we are in the fundamental representation of of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, since $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is its double cover. The representation of the Lie algebra consists of all skew-symmetric $3\times 3$ matrices (since these are the [generators of ordinary rotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Lie_algebra)). Let ($\rho$ suppressed in the following)

$$ T^1 = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right) \quad T^2 = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right) \quad T^3= \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$$

and just expand $\phi = \phi^i e_i$ with $e_b$ as the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to see how $A_\mu^a T^a\phi$ becomes the cross product through the action of the $T^a_{ij}$ on the $e_i$.

---

Another way to see this without the tedious matrix computations is recalling that the vector product is defined by

$$ (a \times b)^i = \epsilon^{ijk} a_j b_k$$

and that the *adjoint representation* of any Lie group $G$ upon its Lie algebra is induced by<sup>1</sup>

$$ \mathrm{ad}(T^a)_{ij} = f^{aij}$$

As it happens, the triplet of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ *is* its adjoint (since there are *three* generators), and the structure constants of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ are just the Levi-Civita symbols $\epsilon^{ijk}$. Plugging this into $D_\mu \phi$ yields the vector product $(A_\mu \times \phi)$-term.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>This is a consequence of the $T^a$ themselves being naturally elements of the Lie algebra, the structure constants being given by $[T^a,T^b] = f^{abc}T^c$ and the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) applied to the adjoint action of $g \in G$ on $T^a$: $\mathrm{Ad}(g)(T^a) = gT^ag^{-1}$.</sup>